# Redirection from android application to playstore market url not working

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I'm working on an android application, up and running at this moment. I wanted to force the existing users to upgrade the app to my latest version. This is how I went about it:

- The app makes an API call to my backend server upon opening, and the server returns back a flag which signifies whether it needs to force the user to update or not
- If it has to force an update, a pop up comes up and redirects the user to the playstore url upon the click of an "upgrage" button.

Now the problem is that upon click of the "upgrade" button, the playstore opens up but shows an "Item not found - Retry" screen. I've the same redirection in the "rate us" section inside the app, and it seems to be working fine there.

How do I get around this problem? Has anyone seen this before? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: show your code of redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Share your code.. try below code in your upgrade script to see if that helps

```
        final Button btnRateUs = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Rate_Us);
        btnRateUs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,

                            Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.rachittechnology.incometaxact1961")));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rachittechnology.incometaxact1961")));

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the main difference with solution given by @RiyazParasara prior than you?

Comment: no difference :). I think we posted approximately at same time

Comment: May be. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void moreapp(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=(Enter id or package) "));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?